# How to open WinBUGS odc file in R?

Tags: r

I'm currently using Ubuntu, R, and JAGS. I'd like to explore a few WinBUGS examples that are available on the web, such as those available on the [website accompanying the book, *Bayesian Modeling Using WinBUGS: An introduction*](http://stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jbn/winbugs_book/).

However, the analyses are stored in the odc format e.g., [this one](http://stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jbn/winbugs_book/files/chap03/chap03_ex1.odc).
I can open the file with a text editor and it does show the model syntax in plain text and in some cases data and so forth. However, I was wondering:

**Is there an existing R function that extracts important elements of a WinBUGS odc file?**

Comment: This link might be interesting: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/rube/rube0.2-16/R/getBugsExample.R

Comment: Thanks. For others, the link above to `getBugsExample.R` provides code for extracting elements out of WinBugs built-in examples. It is self-described as "horrible hack" that gets the job done. Perhaps it could be the starting point for developing a more general function.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend compile [odcread](https://github.com/gertvv/odcread) and use it to convert .odc files to text files and read it with any text editor.

`for f in *.odc; do
  odcread ./"$f" > ./"${f%.odc}.txt"
done`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go and install WinBUGS.

See http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/winbugs/contents.shtml

You can then open any of these directly there, and copy them for use wherever you want.

Comment: that doesn't really help much, as the OP already said they could open ODC files with a regular text editor ...