# How to open WinBUGS .odc file in OpenBUGS and import to R

Tags: r, linux, winbugs, openbugs

I'm trying to open and test [the examples](http://www.wiley.com/legacy/wileychi/lee_structural/material.html) from Lee's (2007) *Structural Equation Modeling: a Bayesian Approach*. The zip file contains a PDF, a DAT file and a file in with .odc suffix for each chapter. I'm interested in accessing the content of the .odc file, but I am not sure how to do so. I presume this is a so-called Oberon compound document file, and should be possible to open in WinBUGS. I am using Linux, however, so my alternative is OpenBUGS.

I am currently wondering if I can access and import its content to R using OpenBUGS and the R2OpenBUGS package or similar?

Answer (score 0):

While OpenBUGS seemingly will allow .odc file to run, I have yet to find a way to access their content this way.

However, a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403059/9434803) is to compile [odcread](https://github.com/gertvv/odcread) ([in AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/odcread-git)) and use this to extract the contents of the .odc:

```
% odcread file.odc > file.txt
```